# Is it possible to train classifier model in simulink?

Tags: simulink

I have a Simulink model where some features are extracted from the signals. I want to train a classifier model (LDA, kNN, etc.) with using these features. Is it possible to do it purely on Simulink? I want to do it on Simulink because, I am trying to simulate real-time online system that gives classification output causally.

I have tried to use fitcdscr and fitcknn functions in matlab function block. But they didn't work.

Comment: Have you declared fitcdscr and fitcknn functions as "coder.extrinsic" in the matlab function block? See  [this page](https://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/calling-matlab-functions.html)